# How to add firebase event listener for nodeJs express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application where all firebase stuff is handled by nodeJs express app.

I want the app to listen to **real-time value changes** through API calls.
But problem is that a POST request made to express server has time-out time for 3-4 mins only after which the request dies. So if there is any change in database which triggers listener then how can I make my app to listen those changes and send back response to the client(who made API request).

Here is sample code snippet of express server app

```
router.post('/listen', (req, res) => {
    //listen to the changes in database

    var ref = db.ref("message").child("new_message_available");

    ref.on('value', snap => {
        var data = snap.val();

        if (data) {
            console.log('New message available')

            res.send({
                'message' : "new message available"
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('No new message available')
        }
    });
});
```

And here is demo firebase realtime database structure

```
{
    'message': {
        'new_message_available': true
    }
}
```

Since POST request lives only for 3-4 mins and change in the database could be made at any time, how to listen to those changes and send back response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible with simple REST apis and requires **Socket** connections with the server where listener is added on the firebase database which on triggering notifies the client connected through socket connection.

There could be multiple ways of socket implementation, I found [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to be best for my usecase. A sample code for the above is as follows:

server side

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http')
const socketio = require("socket.io");

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

// firebase db reference
var ref = db.ref().child(`userPresent`);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    ref.on('value', snap => {

        let data = snap.val()

        if (data == true) {
            io.to(room).emit('userpresent', "User is online");
        } else {
            io.to(room).emit('userpresent', "User is offline");
        }

    });
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
});
```

client side

```
const socket = io()

socket.on('userpresent', message => {
   console.log(`user info : ${message}`)
})
```